# Performing the same code block (yield)

Tags: ruby, methods, block, yield

How can I make sure that the method is executed once. If method A is inserted inside the method Ai as a block to the secondary methods are is not performed. Something like this:

```
def a
  puts "|start|"
  yield
  puts "|end|"
end

a do
  a { "|test_one|" }
  a { "|test_two|" }
end

=> "|start||test_one||test_two||end|"
```

Not like this:

```
=> "|start|test_one|start|end|test_two|end|"
```

Comment: Your example could not work, `a "|test_one|"` will return "invalid number of arguments, because you need to give a block to method `a`

Comment: @Grych I corrected example

Comment: Still not a good example. The block `"|test one|"` just returns the string, does not write anything to the console. Please explain better what do you want to archive

Comment: @Grych I do not understand how I can change the method `a`, to get a result like this: `=> |start||test_one||test_two||end|`

Answer (score 1):

In your current example *you are* calling your function `a` recursively twice.

If you change your code as follow it will execute the block only once and get the output that you describe:

```
def a
  puts "|start|"
  yield
  puts "|end|"
end

a do
  puts "|test_one|"
  puts "|test_two|"
end
```

Comment: It was a simple example. In the real world it is more complex design. And I need to use this:
   <blink>a do
      a { "|test_one|" }
      a { "|test_two|" }
    end</blink>
And I do not know how to change the method:
    def a
      puts "|start|" unless # Here some condition
      yield
      puts "|end|" unless # Here some condition
    end

Answer (score 0):

In your example the method `a` will run three times, because you execute it once in a main part and two time in a block. To have a desired output, you don't have to run this method in a block. Just execute the block which contains two instructions:

```
irb(main):066:0> a do
irb(main):067:1*   puts "|test_one|"
irb(main):068:1>   puts "|test_two|"
irb(main):069:1> end
|start|
|test_one|
|test_two|
|end|
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling method `a` but not printing the block that is been yielded.

`yield` replaces the whole block that has been passed as an argument, inside the method where it is written.

so your method actually becomes like this when ruby interprets the code.

```
  puts "|start|"
  puts "|start|" # 
  "|test_one|"   # replaced for yield on call `a {"|test_one|"}`
  puts "|end|"   #
  puts "|start|" #
  "|test_two|"   # replaced for yield on call `a {"|test_two|"}`
  puts "|end|"   #
  puts "|end|"
```

Output:

```
|start||start||end||start||end||end|
```

If you want to see if what the block is returning then add a `puts` before `yield`

```
def a
  puts "|start|"
  puts yield
  puts "|end|"
end
```

Then call your method the same way and now the output will be.

```
|start||start||test_one||end||start||test_two||end||end|
```

Correct me if I'm missing anything.